# sheets conditional formatting to check individual row cells values against each other

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I need conditional formatting in google sheets to check if the sum of two cells is equal to a third cell and highlight the 3 cells if not.  I would like to set this up with one conditional formatting rule.

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 4.123 |
| 2.5 | 2.5 | 5.0 |
| 2 | 2 | 4.0 |
| 2 | 2 | 4.1 |

e.g. in this example, all three cells in rows 1, 4 should be highlighted.

Ideally with one custom formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values are in the range `A2:C`, use this conditional formatting custom formula rule for the range `A2:C`:

`=$A2 + $B2 <> $C2`